# Flask app using locks and multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, multiprocessing, wsgi

Exposing a database though Flask-based API, I use locks in view functions to avoid issues with non atomic database operations.

E.g. dealing with a `PUT`, if the database driver does not provide an atomic upsert feature, I just grab the lock, read, update, write, then release the lock.

**AFAIU, this works in a multi-threaded environment, but since the lock belong to the Flask app, it fails if multiple processes are used. Is this correct?**

If so, how do people deal with locks when using multiple processes? Do they use an external base such as Redis to store the locks?

Subsidiary question. My apache config is

```
WSGIDaemonProcess app_name threads=5
```

Can I conclude that I'm on the safe side until I don't throw some `processes=N` in there?